# SQL Delete feature does not function in table

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sql-delete

I have three files connecting to each other, my issue is that my delete function does not seem to be working. I'd like to know what is missing in my "public function Delete_Lease($db) {" the codes are shown are shown below. Basically, I use a for each to display a table, the edit works with no problem but the delete just stays on the same page and has no effect.

**Table Name:** for_lease

**Values:** leaseid, lease_type, lease_name, lease_address, lease_price, lease_condition, lease_description, featured_photo, createddate

[image: table]
***for_lease.php***

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once('for_lease.vc.php');
?>

 <?php foreach($lstProperty as $rowProperty) { ?>
       <tr align="center">
         <td>
          <a href="for_lease_edit.php?i=<?php echo($rowProperty['leaseid']); ?>"><input type="submit" class="btn bg-color-blue color-white form-control" name="edit" value="EDIT"></a>
         </td>

         <td>
           <?php
             echo($rowProperty['lease_name']);
           ?>
         </td>

         <td>
           <?php
             echo($rowProperty['lease_address']);
           ?>
         </td>

         <td>
           <?php
             echo($rowProperty['lease_type']);
           ?>
         </td>

         <td>
           <?php
             echo 'PHP'.' '.number_format(($rowProperty['lease_price']));
           ?>
         </td>

         <td>
           <?php
             echo($rowProperty['lease_condition']);
           ?>
         </td>

         <td>
           <?php
             echo( date("Y-m-d", strtotime($rowProperty['createddate']) ));
           ?>
         </td>

         <td>
           <a href="for_lease.php?delete=<?php echo($rowProperty['leaseid']); ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"><input type="submit" class="btn bg-color-red color-white form-control" name="delete" value="DELETE"></a>
         </td>
       </tr>
 <?php } ?>
```

**for_lease.vc.php**

```
<?php
  $routePath = "../";

  require_once($routePath . "_config/db.php");
    $dbConfig = new config_db();
    $db = $dbConfig->init();

  require_once($routePath . "_mc/Property.mc.php");

  $mcProperty = new Property_MC();

  $lstProperty = $mcProperty->SelectObj_ByLeaseId($db);

  if (isset($_GET['delete'])){
    $rowProperty = $mcProperty->Delete_Lease($db);
  }
?>
```

**Property.mc.php**

```
<?php
Class Property_MC {

  public function SelectObj_ByLeaseId($db) {
  $stmt = $db->prepare(
    " SELECT leaseid, lease_type, lease_name, lease_address, lease_price, lease_condition, lease_description, createddate
      FROM for_lease"
  );

  $stmt->execute();
  $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  return $row;
  }

  public function Delete_Lease($db) {
  $stmt = $db->prepare(
    " DELETE * FROM
        for_lease
      WHERE
        leaseid = :leaseid "
  );
  }

} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete_Lease is missing binding and execution as well as what lease id to delete.
the sql for delete does not need the "*".

Property.mc.php

```
public function Delete_Lease($db, $leaseid) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare(
        "DELETE FROM
        for_lease
        WHERE
        leaseid = :leaseid "
        );  
    $stmt->execute(['leaseid' => $leaseid]);
}
```

for_lease.vc.php

```
if (isset($_GET['delete'])){
    $rowProperty = $mcProperty->Delete_Lease($db, $_GET['leaseid']);
}
```

fix delete button that overwrites delete id in for_lease.php

```
<td>
    <a href="for_lease.php?leaseid=<?php echo($rowProperty['leaseid']); ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"><input type="submit" class="btn bg-color-red color-white form-control" name="delete" value="DELETE"></a>
</td>
```

Comment: Update my question, I get unidentified variable if I try to add "leaseid"

Comment: You need to pass the value in - try this.
alos the delete button was over writting the delete value on confirm.

Comment: thanks for the edit, some tweaking with this answer did the trick :) i realised i needed the $_GET

Answer (score 0):

You're not executing the sql statement, you are only preparing it. Also, the way you're code is setup, you will need to pass the `leaseid` to your delete function.

Try this.

**for_lease.vc.php**

```
<?php
  $routePath = "../";

  require_once($routePath . "_config/db.php");
    $dbConfig = new config_db();
    $db = $dbConfig->init();

  require_once($routePath . "_mc/Property.mc.php");

  $mcProperty = new Property_MC();

  $lstProperty = $mcProperty->SelectObj_ByLeaseId($db);

  if (isset($_GET['delete'])){
    $rowProperty = $mcProperty->Delete_Lease($db, $_GET['delete']);
  }
?>
```

**Property.mc.php**

```
 public function Delete_Lease($db, $leaseid) {
  $stmt = $db->prepare(
    " DELETE FROM
        for_lease
      WHERE
        leaseid = :leaseid "
  );

  $stmt->execute([':leaseid' => $leaseid]);  

  }
```

Comment: there is no effect after trying this example